# Integrating a python Tensorflow chatbot model into a Xamarin app

Tags: c#, python, tensorflow, xamarin, python.net

I'm using Xamarin Forms to create a chatbot-like messaging app and I've created a simple chatbot model using TensorFlow and python. The model executes as a console app and after some testing, I've been able to run the python chatbot script in C# console using Pythonnet. I would now like to integrate it into the Xamarin app wherein the users text is taken in as the input and the output is from the chatbot. How would I use this python file as a backend?

**Chatbot.py**

```
#MODULE IMPORTS
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json
import pickle
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

with open("C:/Users/PAVILION/Desktop/Trial3/Conversations/intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)

except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            #STEMMING OF WORDS
            stemmedWords = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(stemmedWords)
            docs_x.append(stemmedWords)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"] 
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))
    labels = sorted(labels)


    training = []
    output = []
    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []
        stemmedWords = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]

        for w in words:
            if w in stemmedWords:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)

        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)

    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)


tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape = [None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")

except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")

def bagOfWords(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]
    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for s2 in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == s2:
                bag[i] = (1)
    return numpy.array(bag)

def chat():
    print("Start talking with the bot")
    while True:
        userInput = input("You: ")
        if userInput.lower() == "quit":
            break
        results = model.predict([bagOfWords(userInput, words)])[0]
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        if results[results_index] > 0.6:
            for tg in data["intents"]:
                if tg["tag"] == tag:
                    responses = tg["responses"]

            print(random.choice(responses))

        else:
            print("Dont understand")

chat()
```

**Chatbot.xaml in Xamarin**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:BluePillApp.Controls"
             xmlns:renderers="clr-namespace:BluePillApp.CustomRenderers"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BluePillApp"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:BluePillApp.Helpers"
             xmlns:xamEffects="clr-namespace:XamEffects;assembly=XamEffects"
             xmlns:pancake="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="BluePillApp.Views.ChatbotPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <helpers:TemplateSelector x:Key="MessageTemplateSelector"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Chat Views-->

        <!--Chat Messages Area-->
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" 
                 Margin="0" 
                 HasUnevenRows="True" 
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 SeparatorColor="Transparent" >
        </ListView>

        <!--A simple separater-->
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Grid.Row="2"/>

        <!--Chat Entry and Send Button-->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     Margin="0" 
                     Grid.Row="3" 
                     Padding="5,10,10,10">

            <!--Chat Entry-->
            <renderers:RoundedEntry Text="{Binding TextToSend}" 
                                    x:Name="ChatEntry"
                                    Placeholder="Type your message"
                                    CornerRadius="30"
                                    BackColor="White"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    BorderColor="#999999"
                                    BorderWidth="5"
                                    FontSize="16"
                                    PlaceholderColor="#b3b3b3"
                                    Keyboard="Chat"
                                    WidthRequest="280"/>

            <!--Send Button-->
            <pancake:PancakeView BackgroundColor="#0f8df4"
                                 CornerRadius="100"
                                 xamEffects:TouchEffect.Color="White"
                                 xamEffects:Commands.Tap="{Binding SendCommand}"
                                 HeightRequest="47"
                                 WidthRequest="47"
                                 HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                <Image Source="sendarrow1.png"
                       HeightRequest="30"
                       WidthRequest="30"
                       Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </pancake:PancakeView>
        </StackLayout>



        <!--Chatbot Header and Back Button-->
        <pancake:PancakeView BackgroundColor="#f7f7f7" Grid.Row="0" HasShadow="True" Padding="0,10,0,10">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                <!--Back Arrow Button-->
                <renderers:FontAwesomeIcon Text="{x:Static helpers:IconsFA.BackArrow}" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                           TextColor="Black"
                                           FontSize="20"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Margin="15,0,0,0">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BacktoMain_Button"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </renderers:FontAwesomeIcon>

                <!--Fleming Image-->
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Gray" 
                           Padding="0" 
                           CornerRadius="100"
                           HasShadow="False"
                           IsClippedToBounds="True"
                           HeightRequest="40"
                           WidthRequest="40">

                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Frame>

                    <!--Fleming Text-->
                    <Label Text="Fleming"
                           TextColor="Black"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="18"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </pancake:PancakeView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**Chatbot.xaml ViewModel**

```
 public class ChatbotPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// A collection.list of chat message items
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ChatMessageModel> Messages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessageModel>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The text that the user inputs
        /// </summary>
        public string TextToSend { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// A command for sending the users messages
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand SendCommand { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// ChatPageViewModel Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public ChatbotPageViewModel()
        {
            Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = "Hi" });
            Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = "How are you?" });

            SendCommand = new RelayCommand(Send);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function sends a message
        /// </summary>
        private void Send()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextToSend))
            {
                //This adds the following to the messages collection
                Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = TextToSend, User = App.User});

                if(TextToSend == "Hey")
                {
                    Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = "Hey yourself"});
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Sample of the full Xamarin Chatbot app I'm developing](https://github.com/Bhyte-Softwares/BluePillApp-Repo)

Comment: Why are you trying to mix 3 languages together here?

Comment: two actually, python and C#. I want to make a Xamarin chatbot app and need it to utilize TensorFlow machine learning, so Python was the only feasible choice. Theres no real machine learning solution for C# except ML.Net which is still in a very early stage.

Comment: the 3rd was that you are most likely compiling this to something else like IOS, or andriod. TensorFlow isnt a python thing, its just a thing you can use it anywhere on any platform

Comment: With Xamarin I believe it would all just be a single C# codebase. And I've done some searching but there's no .NET version of Tensorflow that can do all the things I need it to

Comment: @TheGeneral Is there any way you can think of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

There is some misunderstanding of concepts. You don't need the python file been integrated into XF project. You use Python as a language and TensorFlow as a framework to get ML model. A model is a result of the training process and you could use it in other places like mobile platforms.

For using models on Android you could try to use [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android)

For using models in iOS you should [convert](https://medium.com/@jianshi_94445/convert-a-tensorflow-model-to-coreml-model-using-tfcoreml-8ce157f1bc3b) default format of TF in CoreML format (.mlmodel)

After that, you have to integrate these models into Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects

Comment: I see, so what file format would be used for each platform? Because in my chatbot folder, the model produced a .meta, .index, .pickle and a .data-00000-of-00001 file

Comment: @Draxalot2 default format for TF models is .pb. I see that you use tflearn for training. I'm not familiar with either tflearn or even TF but you could find some solutions for the issue here https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/964

Comment: okay, do you have any knowledge/experience on integrating said model with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: For Xamarin projects - no. But even official docs for Xamarin.iOS [could](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios11/coreml) help if you spend a bit more time for googling it.